# Bijective function on affine space sends coplanar lines to coplanar lines

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

*Context : Work on affine functions*

**Statement :** Let E be an affine space over a field $\mathbb{K}$ , we suppose $Dim(E)\geq 2$

Let $f:E\rightarrow E$ be bijective and we suppose that the image by $f$ of an affine line is an affine line.

Show that if $D_1$ and $D_2$ are two coplanar affine lines , then $f(D_1)$ and $f(D_2$) are coplanar.

**What i have started :** Let's suppose $D_1$ and $D_2$ are two coplanar affine lines. I started by admitting that either $D_1$ and $D_2$ are parallel , either they are intersecting.

In the case they are intersecting : As $f$ is bijective and in particular injective , we have
$$f(D_1 \cap D_2)=f(D_1)\cap f(D_2) $$ which shows that in the case they are intersecting in one point , or if they are intersecting everywhere , it happens to be the same for $f(D_1)$ and $f(D_2)$

But after that , i don't know how to treat the parallel case.

Comment: Hint: In the parallel case consider another two lines which intersect $D_1$, $D_2$ and each other. Than use the non-parallel case.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a trial with Peter K hint but i'll probably have to correct (And i may not have understood it well):

Let's suppose $(D_1)$ and $(D_2)$ are parallel now.
$(D_1)\vert\vert (D_2)\Leftrightarrow $ if $D_3$ intersect $D_1$ then $D_3$ intersect $D_2$.

Let's take $(D_3)$ that intersect $(D_1)$ (And so $(D_2)$ as we suppose them parallel).

Then $f(D_3)$ intersect $f(D_1)$ by the precedent point , and as $(D_3)$ intersect $(D_2)$, $f(D_3)$ intersect $f(D_2)$

Am i missing something ?